# hibernate Exception when execute the jpa sub query

Tags: java

```
query=entityManager.createQuery(" select a.birthDate from PersonalDetailsDomain a where a.empCode=(select b.empCode from User b where b.userId=?)");
    query.setParameter(1,userId);
    Date dob =(Date)query.getSingleResult();
```

Excetion:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: empCode of: com.erp.hrms.User [ select a.birthDate from com.erp.hrms.newjoinee.PersonalDetailsDomain a where a.empCode=(select b.empCode from com.erp.hrms.User b where b.userId=?)]

Comment: Does your "User" entity have an "empCode" property with getters and setters?

Comment: As you are writing Pure SQL Query not the HSQL , you have to given the table name not the POJO Class name of that individual table

Comment: Have you looked at these other questions about jpa & subquries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460235/jpa-2-criteria-using-in-and-subqueries http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187188/jpa-criteria-query-with-subquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662336/subquery-in-select-clause http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483576/jpa-2-0-criteria-api-subqueries-in-expressions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269010/jpa-hibernate-subquery-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0):

Use ':userId' instead of '?' and also use method `createSQLQuery` for native sql queries.

```
query=entityManager.createSQLQuery(" select a.birthDate from PersonalDetailsDomain a where a.empCode=(select b.empCode from User b where b.userId= :userId)");

query.setParameter("userId", userId);

Date dob =(Date)query.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure to have correctly mapped the field (or relative accessor) for User.empCode?
Attach `User` definition, would help.